# has_object_permission not taken into account

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to enforce a permission with Django Rest Framework where a specific user cannot post an object containing a user id which is not his.

For example i don't want a user to post a feedback with another id.

My model is something like :

```
class Feedback(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

I try to put a permission on my view which would compare the feedback.user.id with the request.user.id, the right work ok on a post on an object and return false, but it's still posting my object... Why?

**The View**

```
class FeedbackViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Feedback
    permission_classes = (IsSelf,)
    serializer_class = FeedbackSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        ....
```

**The Permission**

```
class IsSelf(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        #return eval(obj.user.id) == request.user.id
        return False
```

I've commented the line to show where the problem lies.
Again the function is correctly called and returns False, but there's just no PermissionDenied raised.
While at it, i'm wondering if this is actually the way to implement this behaviour, and if not, what would be...?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that has_object_permission is only called if you're trying to access a certain object. So on creation it is never actually used.

I'd suggest you do the check on validation. Example:

```
class FeedbackSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if attrs['user'].id !=  user.id:
            raise ValidationError('Some exception message')
        return attrs
```

If you have some other super serializer class then just change it.

Now that I think of it if the user field must always be the posting user, then you should just make that field read-only and set it on pre_save() in the viewset class.

```
class FeedbackViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    def pre_save(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.action == 'create':
            obj.user = self.request.user
```

And in the serializer set the user field read-only

```
class FeedbackSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', read_only=True)

    ....
```

Comment: But that's the thing, this function is actually called! If it wasn't called, i would have come to the same conclusion, but it IS called, it DOES return false, but still is not taken into account, and this, i don't understand...
Still, the part about the pre_save was exactly the kind of advice i was also looking for, so thanks a lot!

Comment: After you create the object, it is displayed in DRF. So maybe the has_object_permissions() is called when it tries to display your created object

Comment: Oh, ok, this could actually be the case...
I guess I'll have to follow another direction then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still open...
However, in order to work, you should move that line from "has_object_permission" to "has_permission", something like this:

```
class IsSelf(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #your condition
```

Worked for me.

As it was stated in the selected answer

> **has_object_permission** is only called if you're trying to access a certain object

so you have to place your condition under **has_permission** instead.

Comment: has permission wont let us use `obj` var as input